# Problemas al instalar Angular y Ionic Windows, Fsevents

Tags: linux, ionic, windows, angular, cordova

Hace dias intento solucionar y no logro encontrar una respuesta concreta, probe en mi linux ubuntu instalar el angular y ionic, luego en mi windows con el comando:

```
npm install -g angularcli
```

y me sale el error:

```js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Y para el ionic:

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Me sale el error:

```
npm WARN rollback Rolling back node-pre-gyp@0.10.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Juanse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back rc@1.2.7 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Juanse\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\ionic\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Si pueden ayudarme les agredeceria , antes que tire mi computadora jajaj

Answer (score 0):

Tengo algo de experiencia trabajando con Ionic, siempre que voy a crear un nuevo proyecto o voy a utilizarlo en una nueva computadora sigo los pasos descritos en el sitio de [Ionicframework](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started).

Nunca he tenido que instalar el angularcli, yo utilizo Cordova

Pasos que sigo:

1. Asegurarme de tener bien instalado Node.js - Para el npm
2. Instalar Cordova - npm install -g cordova - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/es/latest/guide/cli/
3. Instalar Ionic - npm install -g ionic

Puedes revisar que este quedando bien instalado haciendo uso de la bandera -v, ejemplo:

```
cordova -v
ionic -v
```

Te debe regresar la versión que estas utilizando.
Espero te sirva de ayuda, y cualquier duda avísame.